# Some emails fail to leave the computer

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Every now and again, the Outlook 365 desktop app fails to send emails without warning when the send button is pressed.  As there is no warning, it seems the email has been sent (when it hasn't), and you get into situations when the receiver is expecting an important email, you think you have sent it, and so on.

The email does not appear in the sent, draft, or outbox.

Does something exist which can track send clicks in outlook and if the email was successfully sent or not so we can see if we can find the cause of such failures?

Comment: Find the root cause. But while doing that, and as a temp workaround only, send yourself BCC's

Comment: @Hennes, how do I find the route cause?

Comment: Ah, if I was good at that I would have posted an answer. But outlook/exchange and me are not a good mix. So I only offered a bandage while you stop for a way of getting fresh cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a message track to diagnose the outbound message leave your serve or not.

For mailbox belongs to Exchange on-pre, try the methods in the link below.

[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019)

For mailbox belongs to Exchange Online, try the methods in the link below.

[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results)

Comment: The problematic emails do not reach exchange at all.  It seems to be a client side issue.

Comment: Install the Outlook client in a fresh install client, then try again.

Comment: If they reached exchange then an exchange admin could look at logs. No need to use inreliable tracking.